# create_subprocess_shell resulting in slow_callback_duration warning

Tags: python, performance, debugging, subprocess, python-asyncio

Warning:

`WARNING: Executing Task pending name='Task-2673' coro=BaseSubprocessTransport._connect_pipes() running at /sarc/cad/tools/conda/envs/p3_impl7/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_subprocess.py:168 wait_for=Future pending cb=[TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x2b13f6c66e20()] created at /sarc/cad/tools/conda/envs/p3_impl7/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py:418 created at /sarc/cad/tools/conda/envs/p3_impl7/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_subprocess.py:53 took 0.424 seconds`

Code:

```
cmd = " ".join(cmd)
proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
    cmd, cwd=cwd, env=nenv, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )
stdout, stderr = await proc.communicate()
res = stdout.decode()
```

I am not sure if this code snipped is causing this error, but have thousands of such `create_subprocess_shell` called, each from a independent task. If the slow_callback is infact comming from above code how can I fix it?

Comment: What is `slow_callback_duration`?

Comment: @martineau It is an attribute that can be set to a value above which asyncio will trigger a WARNING when ever any coro execution duration exceeds this value. For formal info: [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html)

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by a [bug in asyncio](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/414). To better reproduce the issue I lowered the threshold `slow_callback_duration`-Warnings:

```
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
loop.set_debug(True)
loop.slow_callback_duration = 0.01 # warn if a subroutine takes longer than 10 ms
```

You can solve it by using `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec` instead. The `_shell` version

> performs at least one blocking read on a pipe

as written in the [bug description](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/414).

Another solution may be to switch to [uvloop](https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop). They also have an [issue](https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop/issues/118), but the ticket says

> uvloop can block only if you supply a `preexec_fn` argument to `loop.subprocess_shell()` or `loop.subprocess_exec()`.